# Can not create process with elevated permissions from LocalSystem account

Tags: windows, permissions, powershell

I am running a build server on windows server 2008 (team city). The builds are run by the Team city agent that runs as a windows service under LocalService account.

One of the builds need to copy a zip file it creates to a remote share, to do this I've got a powershell script that attempts to shell a new process with credentials of a user with appropriate permissions to write to the share. The problem is that the script fails to create the process. I can run the script fine from my admin user (so the script itself would seem to be fine), this makes me think that the LocalSystem account does not have some permission to shell new processes with different credentials or something like that?

Any ideas what this error really means?
Note: I can't see any errors in the security event logs which seems odd(?)

```
$userName = "domain\user"
$password = "password"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $secstr
$command = "Copy-Item d:\file.zip \\remote\share\file.zip"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

Start-Process powershell -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "-encodedCommand", $encodedCommand -credential $credentials -wait
```

Error thrown at Start-Process line

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This command cannot be executed due to the error: Access is denied.
    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
```

Comment: can you configure the account Team City runs under? running it under a domain account is probably the best solution.

Comment: I have done this for now with my own account (and this is working fine) but to do this properly I need to request an account without an expiring password. Where I work these seem to be created with reduced entitlements as trying an existing account of this type does not work. How do I see what entitlements I have on my account that are not present on another one (e.g. this non-expiring password one)? Assuming I can do this, how do I know which entitlements are required (I was assuming the security log would be able to help by flagging this up but apparently not?) - thanks :)

Comment: Run the service under the NetworkService account and assign the computer account permissions to the remote directory.

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33462683/1744774) to [Elevate creditals with powershell via Local System Account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33462446/1744774) at StackOverflow:

> There seems to be a restriction on certain commands when a script is run under *LocalSystem*. This makes sense in terms of security, given that *LocalSystem*:
>
> > has complete unrestricted access to local resources. This is also the disadvantage of LocalSystem because a LocalSystem service can do things that would bring down the entire system.
>
> Reference: [MSDN, The LocalSystem Account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33462683/1744774)